# How to change permissions on cert to be ACL’d to Network Service in a secure service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

I have tried logging-in into the VM and giving permission but it doesn't work as I don't have permission to make changes to private keys it says.

Is there some automated way to change permissions?

**NOTE: It's a secure Service Fabric cluster.**

Answer (score 3):

Add certificates to your Cluster **using an ARM template**. Put the details of certificates that are to used by your application under **os.Profile.Secrets**.

You actually don't need to ACL the certificates to **Network Service**, all you need is to **provide read access** to your application to available certificates by adding following lines to your **ApplicationManifest.xml**

```
<Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="Service1" AccountType="NetworkService" />
    </Users>
  </Principals>
  <Policies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicies>
      <SecurityAccessPolicy GrantRights=”Read” PrincipalRef="Service1" ResourceRef="MyCert" ResourceType="Certificate"/>
    </SecurityAccessPolicies>
  </Policies>
  <Certificates>
    <SecretsCertificate Name="MyCert" X509FindType="FindByThumbprint" X509FindValue="[YourCertThumbrint]"/>
  </Certificates>
```

**More help available :** http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/6a524a56-be43-4655-ac1e-df7c54c9e5ac?category=azureservicefabric